# How to get Google Map API key

Tags: google-maps, dictionary

I have to get latitude and longitude for some ten thousand addresses. Hence i need to pay for `Google` to access `geocoding API`. Once paid, what `Google` will give us as a return (i.e. whether a key). Can we use this key in url: 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project).
2. Create or select a project.
3. Search for Geocoding API
4. Enable the API.
5. List item

Go to Credentials to get a Server
    key (and set the API Credentials).

To use Google Maps API for Work, you must include client and signature parameters with your requests (instead of a key). https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/#client_id